# Create thumbnail from uploaded image in Yii2

Tags: yii2, image-uploading

How can I create a thumb image from uploaded image?

I tried this in my **controller:**

```
<?php
namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Employee;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use yii\imagine\Image;

public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Employee();
    $model->added_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'avatar');

        if (!empty($model->file)) {
            $imageName = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
            $model->file->saveAs('uploads/' . $imageName . '.' . $model->file->extension);
            $model->avatar = $imageName . '.' . $model->file->extension;
            $file = 'uploads/' . $imageName . '.' . $model->file->extension;
            Image::thumbnail($file, 200, 200)->save('uploads/thumb/', ['quality' => 80]);
        }
        if ($model->save()) {
            $this->redirect(\Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('employee'));
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', ['model' =>  $model]);
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work. Image is uploaded, but the thumb isn't created.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set proper paths to the *original* and *thumbnail* images, then [save](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-imagine-image.html) the result:

```
$imgPath = Yii::$app->basePath . '/uploads/'; // as an example
$imgName = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
$fileExt = '.' . $model->file->extension;

$originFile = $imgPath . $imgName . $fileExt;
$thumbnFile = $imgPath . $imgName . '-thumb' . $fileExt;

// Generate a thumbnail image
Image::thumbnail($originFile, 200, 200)->save($thumbnFile, ['quality' => 80]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try with this code

```
$file = Yii::$app->basePath.'/uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
$thumbFile = Yii::$app->basePath.'/uploads/thumb/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
Image::thumbnail($file, 200, 200)->save($thumbFile, ['quality' => 80]);
```

Comment: i will give a try and back to you.

Comment: can you give me Image class?

Comment: $file is making path like this
C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\backend/uploads/emp/fHsDVk-EFe4pxP_ZCtEc4Tmet25tv6N2.jpg

Comment: and $thumbfile C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\backend/uploads/emp/thumb/fHsDVk-EFe4pxP_ZCtEc4Tmet25tv6N2.jpg

Comment: You can download imagine extesion from here. https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-imagine

Comment: but can you see my $file variable and $thumbfile variable?

Comment: my path is like that.. is it okay?

Comment: It is ok. Also check folder permission. What is the error now?

Comment: Image::load($file)->resize(200, 200)->save($thumbFile,80);
pls try this and let me know the output

Comment: i have move my project folder from one pc to another. but now it shows internal server error.. why?

Comment: may be it is a htaccess error. Pls enable apache rewrite module

Comment: how can i set htaccess?

Comment: can you see my htaccess file? i have added into question

Comment: Where should i put Image class?

Comment: currently i have put `yii2-imagine` folder in `vendor/yiisoft` folder. and it is giving me `Class 'yii\imagine\Image' not found` error.

Comment: please install it using composer

Comment: i don't know hot to install using composer

Comment: add "yiisoft/yii2-imagine": "~2.0.0" to the require section of your composer.json. Then run composer update